# How to migrate fireauth users whose provider is not email?

Tags: supabase

**I've posted this question to `firebase-to-supabase` github repository as issue.** 
https://github.com/supabase-community/firebase-to-supabase/issues/20

I have users whose provider is custom token login in fireauth and phone.

In case of custom token, since firebase didn't provider kakao social login, 
 It was actually kakao login, but I used custom token at that time.
Its user json data looks like below.

```
 {
    "uid": "kakao:123",
    "emailVerified": false,
    "displayName": "OOO",
    "photoURL": "https://photourl.jpg",
    "disabled": false,
    "metadata": {
      "lastSignInTime": "Fri, 29 Dec 2023 15:27:29 GMT",
      "creationTime": "Fri, 29 Dec 2023 15:21:03 GMT"
    },
    "tokensValidAfterTime": "Fri, 29 Dec 2023 15:21:03 GMT",
    "providerData": []
  },
```

And I also have users whose provider is phone.

```
  {
    "uid": "123456",
    "emailVerified": false,
    "phoneNumber": "+82101111111",
    "disabled": false,
    "metadata": {
      "lastSignInTime": "Tue, 16 May 2023 06:58:35 GMT",
      "creationTime": "Tue, 16 May 2023 06:58:35 GMT"
    },
    "providerData": [
      {
        "uid": "+82101111111",
        "providerId": "phone",
        "phoneNumber": "+82101111111"
      }
    ]
  },
```

When I run node import_users.js users.josn, It only migrates users whose provider is email.
And import_users.js file shows each json file should have email and providerData property.

```
function createUser(user) {
  var sql =
    "(\n        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', /* instance_id */\n        uuid_generate_v4(), /* id */\n        'authenticated', /* aud character varying(255),*/\n        'authenticated', /* role character varying(255),*/\n        '"
      .concat(
        user.email,
      )
      .concat(
        user.emailVerified ? "NOW()" : "null",      )
      .concat(
        formatDate(user.metadata.creationTime),
      )
      .concat(
        getProviderString(user.providerData),
        "', /* raw_app_meta_data jsonb,*/\n        '{\"fbuser\":"
      )
      .concat(
        JSON.stringify(user),
        "}', 
  return sql;
}
```

But user's json file who signed up with custom token doesn't have email and providerData property.

In this case how can I migrate users to supabase successfully?